# Android studio 2020.3.1 running the simulator takes up a lot of memory on disk C

Tags: android

Why do I remove .android from disk C and still create .android in Disk C when running Android studio 2020.3, and the memory of Disk C will be reduced when running the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Run the project using an Android devide using a USB cable, memory will be distributed.

Compiling will be done on your computer while the application will be running on your Android device.